# Retrieving form option id through ParseForm()

Tags: html, forms, http, go

I am trying to get the option value id from HTML form dropdown.

Let's say I have these lines in my HTML file:

```
<select name="film" id="films">
<option id="1">Godfather</option>
</select>
```

And this in my Go file:

```
func filmFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm()
    film_raw := r.Form["film"]
    film := film_raw[0]
    ...
}
```

This will give me the text from the option (`"Godfather"`), but I need to get the option id (`"1"`) and save it as a variable. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not how HTML [`<form>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp) works. When you use a [`<select>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) in a `<form>`, you have to specify the `name` attribute at the `<select>` - you did this right. And you have to specify the `value` attribute for the [`<option>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp) tags, **not** the `id`. You may specify the `id` attribute too (e.g. if you want to refer to the tag by its id), but that is not what gets sent when the form is submitted.

When the form is submitted, a `"key"="value"` pair will be sent for the `<select>`, where `"key"` will be the value of the `name` attribute of `<select>`, and `"value"` will be the value of the `value` attribute of the `<option>` that is selected.

And you can get the value of a submitted form field by its name using [`Request.FormValue()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormValue), note that this also calls [`Request.Parseform()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseForm) if necessary so you can even omit that call.

See this working example:

```
func formHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if selectedFilm := r.FormValue("film"); selectedFilm != "" {
        log.Println("Selected film:", r.FormValue("film"))
    }

    w.Write([]byte(html))
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", formHandler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}

const html = `<html><body>
<form method="POST" action="/">
    <select name="film" id="films">
        <option value="1">The Godfather</option>
        <option value="2">The Godfather: Part II</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body></html>`
```

When you select `"The Godfather"` and submit, the console shows:

```
2015/12/05 21:18:42 Selected film: 1
```

When you select `"The Godfather: Part II"` and submit, the console shows:

```
2015/12/05 21:18:45 Selected film: 2
```